# List View should not load onBackPressed

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, onresume, onbackpressed

I have Three Activities 
Main Activity , Order Activity , Order Details Activity.

Order Activity has a list view . On click of list View Order Details activity is opened but on back pressed from Order Details Activity the list view is loading again how to stop list view from loading Again

Please Help

Comment: post your code. is there OnResume in Order Activity?

Comment: You need to [make a complete question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of this. You need to at least include relevant code

Comment: You are loading the data on onResume that why it is loading again...try to call in it in your onCreate   And Firstly try to understand the life cycle of Activity and fragment....

Comment: or if are creating another another intent in `onBackPressed()`, please stop that and call super.`onBackPressed()` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //****put your list view setup you already create in oncreate() method
    super.onResume();
}
```

**add bellow oncreate() method in main activity**